# Transclusion in Angular UI Modal not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-directive

The objective of [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/1qraIEZFgGyG27bHNZRV?p=preview) is to transclude elements into an Angular UI Modal from a controller, where the Modal is wrapped by a directive. The solution should follow these premises:

- The directive declares the transclusion of fields. These fields are included in the directive declaration in the controller HTML markup.
- These fields declared in the controller should show up in the Modal.
- The scope of these fields should be accessible in the controller (see that I declared an `input1` variable in the controller that should set a value in the Modal).
- I defined a `content` element to transclude the fields. This element is in the modal's template. I'm not sure when this template is available to transclude it.

To summarize, the objective is to have a set of fields declared in the controller HTML markup and available in the modal, where the modal is wrapped in a directive and the scope is managed in the controller. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<div the-modal control="modalCtl">
    <p>some text</p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="input1" />
</div>

<button type="button" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller("ctl", function($scope,$timeout) {

  $scope.modalCtl = {};

  $scope.input1 = "abc";

  $scope.open = function(){
    $scope.modalCtl.openModal();
  };

});


app.directive("theModal", function($uibModal) {
  return {
    restrict: "AE",        
    scope: {              
      control: "="
    },
    transclude: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
      scope.control = scope.control || {}

      scope.control.openModal = function () {
        scope.instance = $uibModal.open({
          animation: false,
          scope: scope,
          template: '<div>in the template</div><div class="content"></div>'
        });
        element.find('.content').append(transclude());
      };
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: you are trying to append to a modal template before it has even been activated and inserted in dom. Quick test ... `console.log(element.find('.content').length)//0`

Comment: Thanks, I changed the place of `element.find('.content').append(transclude());` right after the modal was created, but still get nothing

Comment: but the modal isn't part of that element...look where it gets inserted in dom (inspect live html in browser dev tools)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have come close enough to achieving your objective with transclusion but, there are a few things you need to consider:

1. First of all, according to [UI Bootstrap docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), there is an `appendTo` property in the `options` for the `$uibModal.open()` method *which defaults to `body`*.

   > If `appendTo` is not specified, the modal will be appended to the `body` of your page and becomes a direct child of the `body`. Therefore querying `.content` in your directive via `element.find('.content')` won't work because it doesn't exist there.
2. Secondly, AngularJS comes with **jQLite**, a lightweight version of jQuery. This implies that there is limited support for most of jQuery's functionalities. One such case is with the `.find()` method which only works with tag names.

   To make it work how it does with jQuery (*although you don't really have to because you could still use `.children()` in a chain to query nested DOM elements*), you'll have to load jQuery before Angular (*which I suppose you have already*).

   Refer [AngularJS docs on `angular.element`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element) for more info.
3. Rendering DOM takes a little bit of time for Angular since it needs to make the correct bindings related to scopes and the views, to complete a digest cycle, and so on.
   Therefore you may end up instantly querying a DOM element which in fact might not have been rendered yet.

   > The trick to wait for DOM rendering and completion of a digest cycle is to wrap your DOM related code into `$timeout` wrapper.

Taking the above points into account, the `openModal` method in the link function of your custom directive `theModal` should look like the following:

```
scope.control.openModal = function () {
    scope.instance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: false,
        scope: scope,
        template: '<div>in the template</div><div class="content"></div>',
        /**
        * Make sure the modal is appended to your directive and NOT `body`
        */
        appendTo: element  
    });

    
    /**
    * Give Angular some time to render your DOM
    */
    $timeout(function (){
        /**
        * In case jQuery is not available
        */
        // var content = element.children('.modal').children('.modal-dialog').children('.modal-content').children('.content');
        
        /**
        * Since you have jQuery loaded already
        */
        var content = element.find('.content');
        
        /**
        * Finally, append the transcluded element to the correct position, 
        * while also making sure that the cloned DOM is bound to the parent scope (i.e. ctl) 
        */
        transclude(scope.$parent, function(clonedContent){
            content.append(clonedContent);
        });
    });
};
```

Note how the `transclude` function gives you control over how you want to bind some transcluded DOM to *a custom scope* and NOT the default directive's scope. The plain `transclude()` call will take the current available scope object into account - i.e. the directive's scope - for binding the transcluded DOM.

### [*Demo*](http://plnkr.co/edit/pChKm1FKDcyfn2iWd4K5?p=preview)

Comment: this works, however when the number of elements in the modal is large, there's a noticeable delay when the modal is rendered, any ideas how to fix that? shouldn't be related to the `$timeout` as it's zero seconds.

Comment: @ps0604, can you make a fork of the plunk so that I can see the issue?

Comment: I made a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/mX5nGEWfu2xWCfLGd6qB?p=preview) which generates `900` input elements all transcluded to the modal and bound to `900` values in the controller; and surprisingly, opening the modal takes less than a second almost all the time. 
I suppose you are using `templateUrl` instead of `template` to keep things separate. If that's the case, then the DOM inside the modal will not get rendered until the data is resolved from the `templateUrl` - and that is what taking too long.

Comment: your solution is fine, I probably have the problem somewhere else

Answer (score 4):

As the previous answers suggest, you can use the `appendTo` property to provide the element of your directive as the parent of the modal.
You can "wait for the modal's template to be rendered" by using the `rendered` promise in the UibModalIstance. ([Documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)).

```
scope.control.openModal = function () {
    scope.instance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: false,
        scope: scope,
        template: '<div>in the template</div><div class="content"></div>',
        appendTo: element  
    });
    // We use the redered promise to make sure
    // the modal's template has been loaded.
    scope.instance.rendered.then(function (){
        // You'll most likely want to pass the `$parent` scope as the first
        // parameter for proper scope binding with your controller.
        element.find('.content').append(transclude(scope.$parent));
    });
};
```

Here's the [modified plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/pLPhndllXvq4IJFS7a67?p=preview)

Comment: I'm getting `scope.instance.rendered is not a function`, any ideas?

Comment: Hey @ps0604, in the forked plunker that I've provided it's working fine.. Maybe you're testing in a different versions of Anuglar UI ? The documentation states that the `open` method returns an object containing a `rendered` promise.

Comment: Hey @ps0604, I've realised that there was a bug in the code I wrote in the answer, but not in the Plunker, hence the plunker was working but not the code I provided. If you are willing to check again by using: `scope.instance.rendered.then(function(){})`

Answer (score 0):

`transclude: true,`

Doesn't work like that, it will insert any markup defined inside the scope of your directive, and will put that markup inside your directive template (where you will put `ngTransclude`). That's not what you are (seemingly) attempting to do.

What you are looking is to define a template, give it a url and provide it to the modal using the `templateUrl` property.

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/some-tpl.html">
    <p>some text</p>
    <input type="text" value="1234" />
</script>
```

**JS**

```
$uibModal.open({
    animation: false,
    scope: scope,
    templateUrl: "/some-tpl.html" // link to template url
})
```

Then you can place your directive/your logic inside the controller you provide the modal.

[Here is an updated plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/PFZs8zg9FJlroRtVzkna?p=preview)

Comment: oops, my bad, fixed it!

Comment: why are you defining `transclude` in your directive? From your answer it seems that it shouldn't be there.

Comment: i'm not transcluding because it's not needed. i'm just providing the modal a template. i only changed your plunk to make a point, i should have removed that.

Comment: I removed transclude from your example and it is not working

Comment: I know, take the `$uibModal.open` routine an place it inside the controller, then place your directive inside the modal template, then you will see the markup you will want to transclude. I can update the plunk if i'm being too ambiguous

Comment: No, the uibModal.open should be inside the directive, that's the purpose of this question. The directive shouldn't be inside the template, it's the other way around.